# Uncaught TypeError: $content.switchClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Show more show less in the JavaScript code returns an error. What am I doing wrong?

**JS Code**

```
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
var $this = $(this); 
var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    

if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
    linkText = "Show less";
    $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
} else {
    linkText = "Show more";
    $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
};

$this.text(linkText);
});
```

**Console Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $content.switchClass is not a function
```

**Included Script Tags**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI?

Comment: jQuery has no `switchClass`, jQuery UI does.

Comment: Attach jquery ui script (http://slyweb.ru/jquerydoc/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js for example) and try again. Should work

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: ^ I don't see jQuery UI, which is what everyone is telling you you're missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing jQuery UI most likely, as switchClass is part of jQuery UI, and not the jQuery library.

Comment: yes, it fixed the problem. but the effect was lost.

Comment: You're welcome Ahmet IsLam. Please mark it as answered if you're satisfied with the response :-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are missing jQuery UI. Your script tags should look like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why load all libs with the neutral `//` and jQuery UI with `http`?

Comment: No reason, I just grabbed it from the address bar