# Uncaught TypeError: $content.switchClass is not a function even with jquery ui

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I have tried solution from this [Uncaught TypeError: $content.switchClass is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664520/uncaught-typeerror-content-switchclass-is-not-a-function) question however, I still get the exact same error, anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Context: Flask application, script links are all include in the layout.html page and the actual javascript code that I am making is include in my index.html page that extends layout.html

script

```html
<!--Script to provide view more/less functionality to reviews-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
            console.log("click");
            var $this = $(this);
            var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
            var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
          
            if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
              linkText = "Show less";
              $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
            } else {
              linkText = "Show more";
              $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
            };
          
            $this.text(linkText);
        });
    </script>
```

include scripts in layout.html

```html
<!--This is in the <head> tag-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--Scripts add end of <body> tag -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

elements I am referencing

```html
<section id="reviews">
        <div class="review-box-container">
            <!-- Get all the data from postgres database-->
            {% for review in reviews.items %}
                <div class="review-box">
                    
                    
                    <div class="content hideContent">
                        <b>What do you like/dislike about the way your course and lecturers?</b>
                        <b>How good are your university's facilities?</b>
                        <b>How good is the support offered by the uni?</b>
                        <b>How does your uni make efforts to increase your employability?</b>
                        <b>Is your university in a good location in terms of distance to accommodation and local amenities?</b>
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="show-more">
                        <a href="#">Show Comments</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I believe that `.switchClass()` is a jQuery UI element: https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/ You must include all the proper libraries. You can use `.toggleClass()` with just jQuery.

Comment: @Twisty Thing is i have but it still isn't working, what libraries am I missing?

Comment: You seem to have too many jQuery libraries.

Comment: @Twisty which ones dont i neeed?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, as I'm not used to flask... but do you need $this and $content to have the $ in front of the variable name?

Since you're using jquery and the variables assigned have $(this) as an example... that might be what's happening.

Either way, I would check in regards to how you're referencing the elements. They don't seem to be registering as the proper type, so JQuery isn't giving you the switchClass method.

Comment: Sorry little confused, are you suggesting i remove $this and $content? I've updated my question with the HTML elements I am referencing if that helps

Comment: I was meaning instead of having:


var $this = $(this);
var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");


Have instead:


var element = $(this);
var parentElement = element.parent().prev("div.content");


Or something like that. Not sure if this would fix or not, but in normal JQuery, variable names generally don't have $ in front

Comment: Yeah unfortunely that doesnt seem to work